# Change default timezone is not working in php

Tags: php

Am trying to get my current time from cpanel

am using this code

```
   date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
   $timestamp = date("H");

   echo $timestamp;
```

It works fine in localhost but in cpanel it shows different time.
So I check cpanel which default time is set here

```
 echo 'Time zone is: '.date('e'); 
 echo 'Time zone is: '.date_default_timezone_get();
```

It shows the result UTC is the time zone, Now how to set my default time zone that is '**Asia/kolkata**'

Anyone Please give me some idea, Thanks in Advance

My cpanel files

[image]

Comment: Is the server's clock correct…? Meaning, is the server actually aware of the correct time, in UTC or elsewhere? How "different" is the time exactly?

Comment: Almost 8 hours @deceze

Comment: Thaaaat… answers about 40% of my questions…

Comment: now my current time is 16:15 but it shows 00:07:58 , actually this time is my current time + 8 hrs

Comment: So, your server’s time is completely off then. You either need to set the actual OS’ clock correctly, or better activate NTP so it keeps track of the time itself.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set your timezone in php.ini and restart server.
https://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/php/setting-the-timezone-for-php-in-the-phpini-file

Comment: Sorry to say this , there is no php.ini and .htaccess file in my cpanel , check my updated image above

Comment: In this case, I think, you sholud to ask you hoster to give you rights for changing php.ini file or ask it to do changes by themself adn restart server after that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set timezone for Apache(web server) or Mysql ?

do you have access to WHM?
do you have access to SSH of your server?
Which version of Apache / PHP / Mysql you are using?

if you are on shared hosting you can not do it from cPanel, thats why required above details.

Thanks

Comment: i have an access to WHM

Comment: Ok Great

GO to WHM Dashboard

Click on "Server Configuration"
Then in new loaded page Click on "Server Time"
Now from that new loaded page From the dropdown menu, select the time zone you wish to change the server to.

Save and restart your server, you are done!